# Merge the html website with react application

Tags: reactjs

I started working with React about 6 months ago and I have one website in html and one application in react. Now I want to make together and run on react default port. when react start I want to open website and then click on one link in website open the react app.

I am trying many ways but unable to figured out solutions.

Somebody could tell me any way to do this?

Comment: I think your html file should be served separately with react app.

Comment: Actually I placed the website html content in react public  folder. But i am not sure where i need to call actual react index.html file

Comment: It open the website but react app getting the error like "Target container is not a DOM element." due to missing the root id

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't want to have just an index.html file as part of the react project? You could then have button on the index.html that can render the app once clicked.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, worked for me.

Let's consider `home.html` as Static HTML Page (not reactjs) and `index.html`as ReactJS APP.

On `Link`/`Login` press from home.html, I want to render `reactjs app`.

Link to URL `/#/login` (login button on home.html) as I'm using `HashRouter` (react-router v3).

```
<li>
   <a class="page-scroll" href="/#/login">Login</a>
</li>
```

Now in index.html in `public` folder of Reactjs. Indicated that if URL is just `/` render `home.html`.

```
<script>
    var url = window.location.href;
    if (!url.replace(/.*#\//, '')) {
        location.href = 'home.html'
    }
</script>
```

I put both **index.html** and **home.html** inside same directory/.

Comment: Thanks @Revansiddh, It worked for me and you saved me a lot.